# java -jar works OK but java -classpath throws exception

Tags: java, jar, classpath, noclassdeffounderror

I want to use `java -cp` instead of `java -jar`, because I want to be able to run different classes from a single jar.

I have a package *myPack* with class *myClass*, which are packed into *myJar.jar*. Among other things, the package imports *org.slf4j.LoggerFactory*;

If I run

> java -jar myJar.jar

the program works fine.

But if I run

> java -cp myJar.jar myPack.myClass

it throws `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory`.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Is that class in the classpath?

Comment: You haven't added the slf4j jar file in the classpath, so Java can't know where to load the necessary classes.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004206/how-do-jar-manifest-classpath-and-classpath-command-line-option-combine

Comment: How can I add slf4j.jar if it is packed into myJar.jar?

Comment: Check the Classpath Entry in the jar's Manifest

Comment: @JB
That's what I have found in the manifest: Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar slf4j-jdk14-1.6.6.jar

Comment: So, add these two jar files in the -cp option. The manifest in the classpath is only considered when using the -jar option.